Perl module missing in Overleaf
The package memoize is very useful for externalizing figures, and I have been successful in setting it up on my computer. It requires perl, and its module PDF::API, which I was able to get set up.
I have tried doing this in Overleaf for a large project, but overleaf doesn't automatically load PDF::API when I call \usepackage{memoize}.
Overleaf gives the error:
Package memoize (perl-based extraction) Error: No suitable Perl module for PDF processing was found, options are PDF::API2, PDF::Builder.
MWE (works locally, but not on Overleaf)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{memoize}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw circle(1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

THE (Overleaf) LOG
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.8.9)  7 SEP 2024 18:17
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks17
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen141
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen142
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
Package: pgf 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen143
\Gin@req@width=\dimen144
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks19
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks20
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks21
))
\pgf@x=\dimen145
\pgf@y=\dimen146
\pgf@xa=\dimen147
\pgf@ya=\dimen148
\pgf@xb=\dimen149
\pgf@yb=\dimen150
\pgf@xc=\dimen151
\pgf@yc=\dimen152
\pgf@xd=\dimen153
\pgf@yd=\dimen154
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count196
\c@pgf@countb=\count197
\c@pgf@countc=\count198
\c@pgf@countd=\count199
\t@pgf@toka=\toks22
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks23
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks24
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count266
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count267
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count268
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 274.
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen155
\pgfmath@count=\count269
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks25
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks26
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks27
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count270
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen156
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen157
\pgf@picminy=\dimen158
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen159
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen160
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen161
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen162
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen163
\pgf@xx=\dimen164
\pgf@xy=\dimen165
\pgf@yx=\dimen166
\pgf@yy=\dimen167
\pgf@zx=\dimen168
\pgf@zy=\dimen169
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen170
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen171
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen172
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen173
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfpic=\box53
\pgf@hbox=\box54
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box55
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count271
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen174
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen175
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen176
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen177
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen178
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@max=\dimen179
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count272
\pgf@shadingcount=\count273
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box56
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box57
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen180
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen181
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen182
\pgffor@skip=\dimen183
\pgffor@stack=\toks28
\pgffor@toks=\toks29
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count274
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen184
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen185
\tikz@lasty=\dimen186
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen187
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen188
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen189
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen190
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen191
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen192
\tikz@figbox=\box58
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box59
\tikz@tempbox=\box60
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box61
\tikztreelevel=\count275
\tikznumberofchildren=\count276
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count277
\tikz@fig@count=\count278
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count279
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count280
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count281
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count282
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoize/memoize.sty
Package: memoize 2024/03/15 v1.2.0 Fast and flexible externalization
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count283
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/advice/advice.sty
Package: advice 2024/03/15 v1.1.1 Extend commands and environments
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collargs/collargs.sty
Package: collargs 2024/03/15 v1.2.0 Collect arguments of any command
\collargsArgs=\toks30
\collargsArg=\toks31
\collargs@begins=\count284
) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2024-03-14 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-03-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count285
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box62
))
Package: xparse 2024-03-14 L3 Experimental document command parser
))
\mmz@temptoks=\toks32
\mmz@box=\box63
\mmz@out=\write4
\mmz@mdfive@source=\toks33
\mmz@exec@source=\toks34
\mmzContext=\toks35
\mmzContextExtra=\toks36
\mmzCMemo=\toks37
\mmzCCMemo=\toks38
\mmz@seq=\count286
\mmz@ccmemo@resources=\toks39
\mmz@tbe@box=\box64
\mmzExternPages=\count287
\mmzExtraPages=\count288
\openout0 = `output.mmz.log'.

runsystem(memoize-extract.pl  -F latex output )...executed.

(./output.mmz.log

! Package memoize (perl-based extraction) Error: No suitable Perl module for PDF processing was found, options are PDF::API2, PDF::Builder.

See the memoize (perl-based extraction) package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 ...instructions is section 1.1 of the manual?}
                                                   
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13187 strings out of 474104
 279754 string characters out of 5743486
 1925493 words of memory out of 5000000
 35370 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 102i,0n,107p,405b,90s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


well if is not there it is not there. Try the extract=tex method or ask the overleaf support for help.

Thank you for sparing me going down a rabbit hole. The extract=tex method still doesn't work, so I'll try reaching out to overleaf.

this was why I asked about overleaf on your earlier question ;). I didn't know overleaf even had memoize. (I thought they only updated once a year?)
